# Recommendation for Windows 10 Cloning Software

Tags: windows-10

There are 10 PCs that I should install Windows 10 on, as like as with a few other applications, including configuring them. I know that there is a way to clone the entire SSD with Wavlink, but the PCs have warranty, so I can't really open them. Could you recommend software which is able to create an image of the entire operating system, so I clone it on the rest PCs. I know about Acronix, but I kinda don't know how to use it.

Comment: Acronis is great. If you have it, learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clonezilla, a stalwart in the linux community, also works for windows cloning.  Download clonezilla iso and burn to bootable disk.  You may have to temporarily reset boot order in bios to boot clonezilla disk first. Upon a boot into clonezilla you can select the windows partition and manufacture a complete clone.  You can also create a bootable usb image.

clonezilla is free.